# Location of IWebProxy implementation for .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, webproxy

What is the available implementation of the System.Net.IWebProxy (from System.Net.Primitives, DNX Core)? By application requirement, the only framework can be used in dnxcore50, so what is the right NuGet package that contains proxy implementations?

What is the correct way to resolve such questions? Related functionality seems to be split among dozen of packages.

Answer (score 10):

Despite the name, IWebProxy implementation does not actually need to implement any proxying, it just provides information about the proxy. So, you can create your own implementation:

```
public class MyProxy : IWebProxy
{
    public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
    {
        return new Uri("http://localhost:8888");
    }

    public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not having a default implementation just as you have here seems like an oversight.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `WebProxy` class in the `System.Net` namespace (source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v2.0.3/src/System.Net.WebProxy/src/System/Net/WebProxy.cs)) that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project.json file has these two lines under "dependencies"

```
"frameworks": {
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29",
        "System.Net.Primitives": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to add there dependencies I get errors: "Package Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29 is not compatible with netstandard1.6", "Package Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10 is not compatible with netstandard1.6"